# radio button values not being submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, radio-button

I must be losing my mind...

I have a form with some radio buttons, but no matter what, the POST is only including the NAME of the radios, not the value of whichever is selected:

```
   <input type="radio"  name="storage" value="1" id="ds_d">
   <input type="radio"  name="storage" value="2" id="ds_p">
   <input checked type="radio"  name="storage" value="3" id="ds_n">
```

With the 2nd radio selected (val 2; ds_p), and submited, this is the var_dump:

```
["storage"]=>  string(1) "0"
```

in fact, it is that exact same var_dump no matter which is checked.

WTH is going on?

thx.

ps, the form is loaded into another div via jquery, if that matters.

---

edit: it appears to be something with the ajax. this is the code that loads the form:

```
$.get('/page/init/', function(data){
    $("#form_txt").html(data);
});
```

---

edit 2: just to be clear: it behaves the same whether I submit via a "submit" button, or if I submit it through ajax `serialize()`.

Comment: I just tested your exact code...  'storage' => string '3' (length=1) Makes me think it is an issue with how it is loaded, perhaps the values are not getting set?  Even without the value field it should still return 'on.'  Could you link to a demo or provide some more code?

Comment: did you try it w/o the jquery piece?

Comment: It appears the jquery component is a factor. Let's see that code as well.

Comment: Did you try adding a different type, like a text field? Helps you figure out whether it's a problem with the radios or with the form in general.

Comment: @sprain the radios are part of a larger form; checkboxes, textfields, everything else is working as expected. @luckytaxi : id did try it out without the jquery loading, it works correctly. @webbiedave: yes, ill add it in. @Gazler: don't have a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that I had a jQuery function that cleared out textboxes etc. on focus, and it was calling all inputs, e.g.

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).val('');
});
```

so I had to tell it not to blank the val of the radios:

```
$('input:not(:radio)').focus(function(){
    $(this).val('');
});
```

tricky little bugger.

Thanks for the help....